# Y axis recorded when it's not supposed to be

Tags: animation, graph-editor, axis

So i tried to move the object on x axis only (g key,then x). But everytime, the y axis always get recorded. How can i cancel this?

Also, my blender has become strange, specifically for the graph editor. sometimes the movement stop in the middle of keyframes when usually it'll stop at the end of the keyframe. i don't know when this happened but it's really trouble me especially when i move across multiple axis.

Thank you!

[image: Here's the screebshot]

Comment: delete the Y Location track afterwards in the Dope Sheet or in the Graph Editor? I don't know if there's a way to save only on one or two axis

Comment: Open the 'N' panel in the 3D view and go to Item. Move your model in the X direction, then right-click on the X Location in the Transform panel and select 'Insert single Keyframe'. For your other problem, I assume you don't have Auto Keying selected in the Timeline window? (White dot selected in the middle of the timeline header)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this behaviour is related to how bones local space is working: every bone considers the orientation of its parent as its Local space; if the bone is the highest in hierarchy (root bone) it relates to the orientation of the Armature object.

This means that if the armature object and/or a parent bone is oriented in a different way than world orientation, moving a bone on X (World) axis will be achieved with a local movement of two or three (Local) axis, and this is reflected in the graph editor values.

Sometimes it can be useful to add a new control bone, orient it as needed in edit mode, set it as target of a "child of" bone constraint on the original controller, perform and edit the animation, then bake the result on the original bone (clearing the constraint), so that a movement happening on two or three axis can be edited using one curve only.

The second question is more difficult to understand, maybe it's simply related to the default ease in and ease out of the curves (you can switch them to linear interpolation, to test if it's the case). If not, you should upload your file, to be inspected.